# Why adding objects to a static Collection causing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, collections

I am attempting to add 2 sub-class objects to a static Collection of super-class objects. However, when I try to add the objects to the Collection, I'm receiving a null pointer exception and I'm trying to figure out why.

```
public class MoverLogic{
    static Collection<Super> superCollection;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubAlpha sub1 = new SubAlpha();
    SubBeta sub2 = new SubBeta();
    superCollection.add(sub1); //I'm getting the null pointer exception here
    superCollection.add(sub2);
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `superCollection` first.

Comment: You should really **read** the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: How is it that questions like this come up every day? Either teachers are so bad, or it is for some reasons hard to understand that references are initialized with `null`. Anyway, it shows that it is counter-intuitive to have stated "superCollection is a Collection" and then to find that it is not. Remedy would be if java would demand explicit initialization of all variables.

Comment: @Ingo Sorry mate, I never had any teachers.

Comment: So, @TomFang, do you think it would have helped you if the compiler would have said something like: "error on line 2: please iniialize variable superCollection!"

Comment: @TomFang So pick one of the answers as answering your question and move on. Now you know. A reference has nothing in it unless you put something in it.

Answer (score 3):

Members of a class are initialized to default values when a class is constructed (or loaded statically as in your case)--like `int`s to 0, `boolean`s to false, etc. Similarly, objects are initialized to `null`.

So in your case, `superCollection` is initialized to `null`, and when you use it, you get a `NullPointerException`. It is common to think collections are initialized to empty collection objects, but that isn't the case. Besides, which `Collection` do you mean? `ArrayList`? `LinkedList`?

So something like

```
static Collection<Super> superCollection = new ArrayList<>(); //Java 7
```

would work. Or with any other `Collection` you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to initialize `superCollection` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `superCollection`.
Before anything you have in your `main`, write:

```
superCollection = new ArrayList<Super>();
```

If you aren't going to change the actual collection reference, it might be beneficial of creating it directly in the declaration and adding the `final` modifier:

```
static final Collection<Super> superCollection = new ArrayList<Super>();
```

You will still be allowed to `add` or `remove` elements, but you can't re-assign it to anything else.

*NOTE:* You might change `ArrayList` to a different concrete impelementation of `Collection` if it doesn't suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your collection object eg.

```
 static List<Super> superCollection=new LinkedList<Super>();
```